# CSS animation on unhover

Tags: css, animation, sass

I have a button that fades to another color when you hover over it, however, when you unhover, the color just changes to the original, which doesn't surprises me since I haven't done anything to make it **fade** back to it's original color. In other words, make the animation bellow run when I stop hovering the button, but in reverse. Can someone help me make do this?

Here is my scss code, though I don't mind if you guys help me with pure CSS:

```
#start-vote {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:  0 $pdn-lf;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #755bea, #ff72c0);
    &:hover {
        animation-name: bubble-hover;
        animation-duration: .5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-play-state: running;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }

    @include md() {
        font-size: 27px;
        padding: 18px 54px;
    }

    @include lg() {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 12px 36px;
    }
}

@keyframes bubble-hover {
    0% {
        background: #755bea;
    }
    100% {
        background: #55e7fc;
    }
}
```

Any help would be apreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just apply the same animation to the normal state, like this:

```
#start-vote {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:  0 $pdn-lf;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #755bea, #ff72c0);
    animation-name: bubble-hover;
    animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    &:hover {
        animation-name: bubble-hover;
        animation-duration: .5s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        animation-play-state: running;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }

    @include md() {
        font-size: 27px;
        padding: 18px 54px;
    }

    @include lg() {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 12px 36px;
    }
}

@keyframes bubble-hover {
    0% {
        background: #755bea;
    }
    100% {
        background: #55e7fc;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, but I had to create another `@keyframes` but with the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't transition to a gradient color. Any idea on how to do this? @Yaiza del Río

Answer (score 0):

I think your animation is only working on :hover. You need an animation outside the :hover working in the opposite direction on #start-vote (not inside :hover)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the transition property it'll work:

```
#start-vote {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:  0 $pdn-lf;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #755bea, #ff72c0);
    transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    &:hover {
        animation: bubble-hover .5s forwards running steps(1);
        transition: animation 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    @include md() {
        font-size: 27px;
        padding: 18px 54px;
    }

    @include lg() {
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 12px 36px;
    }
}

@keyframes bubble-hover {
    0% {
        background: #755bea;
    }
    100% {
        background: #55e7fc;
    }
}
```